# Azure active directory application registration for localhost and production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I successfully registered my ASP.NET MVC application to work with Azure AD. Currently the Sign-on URL parameter (Azure Active Directory->App registrations->New Application Registration) looks like https://localhost:44302/

But for production it apparently will be another (say, https://mycoolapp.com)

How should set up the application so that I could use Azure AD locally (for ex. for debugging) and in production.

Changing the Sign-on URL parameter every time doesn't seem to be a good option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can make it work easily without changing sign-on URL every time. You just need to make sure that both URLs.. i.e.  https://localhost:44302/ as well as https://mycoolapp.com are available in the Reply URLs for this application.

The value for Sign-on URL that you give at the time of creating app registration goes into two places. It becomes the Home Page URL under Properties for your web application and it also gets added as the first URL in the Reply URLs collection for your web application. Just make sure to add a the second URL to the Reply URLs collection after your app is registered and that's all.

[image]

[image]

On a side note, even though you can make things work with a single app registration for both production and localhost debugging, you may want to think about having two separate application registrations for production v/s local development and give permissions to production application only for administrators/dev ops if it makes sense.

Imagine any sensitive settings, like if you are using a secret key for your web application, you may not want your development team to have access to secret key for your production app registration even while debugging code. You can always change which app registration gets used in dev v/s production code based on configurations.

It's some of the headaches like these where Managed Service Identities are very appropriate, but whether that makes sense or not is a little different discussion than this one.

Comment: do you mean to change ClientId and RedirectUrl by use of web.config transformation?

Comment: 1. Simple way to make it work - Just go to "Reply URLs" for your application settings and make sure both production and localhost URLs are available there. Whichever is missing right now, add it and then click save. Look at the 2nd screenshot that I have in my answer

Comment: 2. Longer route (only if you want to keep separation between your local development app registration v/s your production app registration) - Only in this case.. you can create two separate application registrations.. one with Production sign on URL and another with Local sign on URL.. then as you said.. decide which ClientID gets used by the web.config transformation. This isn't the only approach, just an option and hence I say that you can choose either one.. 1 (simple way) or 2 (Longer route) depending on what makes sense for your application scenario..

Comment: I did make sure that both production and localhost URLs are available there, But production still redirects to localhost after signing in. https://www.screencast.com/t/L2ScpuZWx
I wonder how production (or localhost) environment should know which reply url to choose?

Comment: ok got it. I guess that might be because of a fixed redirect URL that is getting read from the configuration like in the ASP.NET MVC sample here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp. If that is the case for you as well, make sure to use config transformations to set different values for Production ("https://mycoolapp.com") vs Local ("https://localhost:44302"). Now since you have both of them as valid reply URLs in your App Registration's reply URL collection.. it will work for both production and local. Try it out.

Comment: This is the code that I'm referring to in sample...   

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp

public class Startup
{
    // The Client ID (a.k.a. Application ID) is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in
    string redirectUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUrl"];

Answer (score 1):

I would specify the production URL as the Sign-on URL and the production + localhost as the redirect-URL (since you can add **multiple** redirect-urls!).

See: [Register a new application using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app)

Comment: I've checked: If I add https://localhost:44302 to reply URLs on the portal it redirects me to localhost after signing in (production, xyz.azurewebsites.net)
I didn't get what you mean under _and the production + localhost as the redirect-URL_

Comment: You can add multiple reply-urls

Comment: I did add multiple urls